# Checksum for the FreeD protokoll

Tags: udp, augmented-reality, checksum

i am playing around with the FreeD Protokoll and an Esp32.

I Can't figure out how I get the checksum.

I have UDP Datagramm from another working systhem 29 Bytes:

d1 ff  27  24  92  f1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 5a 00 0f ff 05 55 db  .

The Last byte (db) is the checksum.  The documentation says only : " Checksum of the first 28 Bytes. The checksum is calculated by subtracting (modulo 256) each byte of the
message, including the message type, from 40 (hex). " The message Type is d1.

Thanks for your help.

Addition in a 8 bit int value mikrocontroller does not worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
uint cksum = 0x40;
for (int i=0; i < udpBytes.length -1; i++)
    cksum -= (uint)udpBytes[i];
cksum %= 256;
```